# Android Timer speed increases

Tags: java, android, thread-sleep

I'm very new to android and I'm having a little trouble with a timer. It works fine initially, but every time I click the button to restart it, the speed increases. So over a period of time it starts going very quickly.

Can someone tell me how can I prevent this:

```
if (game_start==false) {
    game_start=true;

    textfield=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVTimer);
    handler=new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(Running){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        number=number+1;
                        time_done=number-prev_time;
                        System.out.println("timer" + time_done);
                        // textfield.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Comment: When you click the button, do you initialize the `number` value again ?

Comment: Yes, i tried setting number=0 at the start every time but what it does is: if previous game was 1,2,3,4....now in the new game it starts like 1,5,2,6..

Comment: When restarting, do you kill any previous threads or will there be always one more thread updating the same values once a second? Also, for delays like this consider just `postDelayed()` instead of a separate thread.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean @laalto. Is it possible that I kill the thread every time and start a new one?

Comment: I am agree with @laalto. Thread must be interrupted before starting the new one. Hold the thread in a object and before starting new one kill the old one.

Comment: Thanks. Can someone please tell me a little about how can I hold the thread in a object and kill the old one ?

Comment: Thread t = new Thread();
      
      t.start();
      
      if(!t.isInterrupted()){
         t.interrupt();
      }

Answer (score 1):

Actually onClick a new instance of thread starts and uses **number** & **prev_time** variables which is out of scope of thread. To prevent this just reset the value of **number** & **prev_time** variables on button click.

Comment: Already tried initializing to 0, but doesn't dove the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at  java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()

Comment: that does not even fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cancelled the original `Runnable` first? You should store a reference to your `Runnable` using an attribute and call `Handler.removeCallbacks (yourHandlerHere)` before starting or when starting your timer

Also, I would recommend you only use a `Handler` and a `Runnable` for a timer instead of a `Thread` (unless you reallllyyy *emphasizing* have to).